# iOS/Obj C: Variable allocations and release

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to print (log) what are the below variables are stored in stack and heap. I want to know where are these below variables are stored in this program. My feel is, except the first two variables , others are storing in heap.

```
-(void) MyFunction
{
    flat value = 9.5; // Stored in Stack?
    int count;   // Stored in Stack?
    NSString *myString = @"Incoming message";  // Stored in Heap
    NSArray *myArr = [[NSArray alloc] init];   // Stored in Heap

    .......
    .......
}
```

In this case, how do i release those, using 'release'?

1. How can i print/log where these variables stored in stack/heap?
2. Does my assumption storing location(heap/stack) mentioned in above program is correct or wrong?
3. If an allocated objects stored in heap memory, their references will also be in heap only (or) reference will be in stack?

Comment: `NSString *myString = @"Incoming message";  // Stored in Heap` - from where you got that idea?

Comment: It's not a terrible idea; it just happens to be incorrect in this case. In gcc, without `-fconstant-cfstrings`, it actually might be stored on the heap (I'd have to double-check).

Comment: @RobNapier I didn't say that it's a terrible idea - what's wrong with it is that it's based on an assumption which OP doesn't happen to have checked for being true or false.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to print (log) what are the below variables are stored in stack and heap. I want to know where are these below variables are stored in this program.

It's very unlikely that you really want to do that, but you can like this:

```
NSLog(@"value:%p", &value);
NSLog(@"count:%p", &count);
NSLog(@"myString:%p", myString);
NSLog(@"myArr:%p", myArr);
```

Regarding where they're stored:

```
float value = 9.5; // Stored in Stack?
```

Probably, if you actually modify it. It might also be stored in a register. Or it might be completely optimized away if it turns out to be constant. The above log statements will force it to be stored on the stack (so it can have an address), so asking where the variable is stored can actually change where it is stored.

But yes, as a back-of-the-envelope approximation of unoptimized code, automatic variables are stored on the stack.

```
int count;   // Stored in Stack?
```

Again, probably. Of course if you never access it, it could be completely optimized away.

```
NSString *myString = @"Incoming message";  // Stored in Heap
```

The constant string that this points to is stored in the text segment (in the code itself). The `myString` pointer itself is an automatic variable, however, and that is stored on the stack as above.

```
NSArray *myArr = [[NSArray alloc] init];   // Stored in Heap
```

This could be optimized down to a constant empty array stored in the framework. Or it could be on the heap.

> In this case, how do i release those, using 'release'?

No. You manage these using ARC, which will manage retains and releases for you. You should not manually call release in most code.

> If an allocated objects stored in heap memory, their references will also be in heap only (or) reference will be in stack?

The pointer variable itself is stored on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can log the values of pointer variables with the `%p` format specifier, e.g.: `NSLog(@"%p", myString);`
   However that in itself won't tell you whether a given address is in a particular memory segment (though you can generally make some educated guesses based on address ranges -- for example, stack addresses begin at the end of a program's address space, so their values tend be much larger than heap addresses; distinguishing heap addresses from static addresses can be a little tricker though).
2. You're correct in thinking that `value` and `count` will be store on the stack, but the object `myString` refers to will be stored in static memory rather than in heap. However, `myArr` will be allocated in heap.
3. Automatic variables (method and function arguments, and local variables not explicitly declared `static`) are allocated on the stack, regardless of the values you initialize them with.